# How Do I Access This Variable?

Tags: ruby, scope

```
class Player
  def getsaves
    print "Saves: "
    saves = gets
  end
  def initialize(saves, era, holds, strikeouts, whip)
  end
end
```

I have the code above...lets say I then write.

```
j = Player.new(30, 30, 30, 30, 30)
```

I want to access the saves variable in `getsaves`
When I am outside the class scope, how do I do this?:

```
puts saves variable that is inside getsaves
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've written it, not only is the `saves` variable inaccessible from outside the class scope, it goes out of scope *at the end of the `getsaves` method*.

You should do something like this instead:

```
class Player
  def getsaves
    print "Saves: "
    @saves = gets # use an instance variable to store the value
  end
  attr_reader :saves # allow external access to the @saves variable
  def initialize(saves, era, holds, strikeouts, whip)
  end
end
```

Now you can simply use `j.saves` to access the `@saves` variable.