# How Do I Access This Variable Inside Intitalize?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do I Access This Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055552/how-do-i-access-this-variable)

Lets say I have the code:

```
class Player
  def getsaves
    print "Saves: "
    saves = gets
  end
  def initialize(saves, era, holds, strikeouts, whip)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to access the saves variable in getsaves in the initialize method say:

```
j = Player.new(getsaves_saves_variable, 30, 30, 30, 30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the attributes:

```
attr_accessor :saves_attr
attr_accessor :era_attr
attr_accessor :holds_attr
attr_accessor :strikeouts_attr
attr_accessor :whip_attr

def initialize(saves, era, holds, strikeouts, whip)
   self.saves = saves
   self.era_attr = era
   ...
end
```

then in getsaves you can do:

```
self.saves_attr = gets
```

Comment: Doing `self.saves=` is a somewhat-backwards way to say `@saves =`. Also `attr_accessor` can take a list of symbols.

Comment: I like the self way of doing things as since @saves wasn't explicitly declared in the code it reads cleaner.  I can see i defined an attribute, and I can see I am using an attribute.  they act the same, but I feel one reads better.

Comment: Well, `self.saves=(val)` just does `@saves = val` anyway, and I would say that `def saves=(val)` isn't explicitly declared either since it's just defined by `attr_accessor`. Further, instance variables never need to be declared either since they're all `nil` by default anyway.